# MySql Error 1093 trying to UPDATE using two databases and two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

DataBase_1 has a list of users with their vBulletinId

DataBase_2 has the vBulletin users with their vBulletinId and UserGroupId

I want to find all vBulletin users from Database_2, who are NOT in Database_1, and change their UserGroupId to 15

```
UPDATE database_2.user 
SET 
    usergroupid = 15
WHERE
(
    SELECT UserId
    FROM database_2.user 
    WHERE UserId NOT IN 
    (
            SELECT vBulletinId 
            FROM database_1.Users 
    )
);
```

Currently I am getting a *"You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause"*

Any help would be great. thanks.

=== SOLUTION ===

A simplified solution that worked.

```
UPDATE database_2.user 
SET 
    usergroupid = 15
WHERE userid NOT IN 
(
    SELECT vBulletinId FROM database_1.Users
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE database_2.user
LEFT JOIN database_1.Users ON database_2.user.UserId = database_1.Users.vBulletinId 
SET database_2.user.usergroupid = 15
WHERE database_1.Users.vBulletinId IS NULL
```

or

```sql
UPDATE database_2.user
SET database_2.user.usergroupid = 15
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM database_1.Users
                   WHERE database_2.user.UserId = database_1.Users.vBulletinId )
```

Comment: Thanks. But this query takes too long, and my connection is dropped after 30 seconds. I tested it first with a SELECT FROM.

Comment: @Bubba This may be due to uncomfortable tables statistic. `NOT EXISTS` variant added - check.

Comment: Thanks. For the `NOT EXISTS` variant, I had to set a limit of 50 rows (which took 18 second). 100 rows would trigger the 30 second timeout. I know from running my `SELECT` query above, there are 37,717 users in db2 (197k) that are not in db1 (160k). So I guess I need something that take less processing time. For some reason, the `NULL` takes way too long.

Comment: @Bubba Does the indices by the columns used in joining exists in the tables?